# WCF service endpoint localhost confusion

Tags: .net, wcf, localhost, endpoint

I'm confused as to why something works. I'm configuring a wcf service like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="ClientCommand" behaviorConfiguration="SomeServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint contract="IClientCommand" binding="netTcpBinding" BindingConfiguration="TcpPort" address="net.tcp://localhost:1304" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The BindingConfiguration and behaviorConfiguration are very simple, just configuring some timeouts.

In my exe, I start the host like this.

```
_serverHost = new ServiceHost(type); // implementing IClientCommand
_serverHost.Open();
```

It's all pretty simple and it works, I can call this service from a different pc. However, after reading up on a different issue (listening on tcp sockets), I get the impression it shouldn't work. As I'm binding to *localhost* the service should not be accessible from outside the pc it's running on?
I checked netstat on the pc and it did bind to ip address "0.0.0.0" instead of "127.0.0.1" explaining why it works from another pc.

But I don't get why it goes from localhost to "0.0.0.0"?

Comment: I digged a little deeper, only to get more confused. If I use `net.tcp://127.0.0.1/service` , it will indeed bind to the loopback and it will not be reachable from outside of the pc. However `net.tcp://localhost/service` will bind to 0.0.0.0 and be reachable from outside the loopback. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Net.tcp is not restricted to communication on one machine, perhaps you are thinking on net.pipe? Regarding 0.0.0.0: How is the host file defined on the machine running the service?
[Here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) is a nice article on WCF in general.

Comment: Hi, I'm not saying net.tcp is restricted to communication on one machine. I'm saying that if you use net.tcp://localhost:... it should be bound to the loopback address and not be reachable from outside the pc. But it is.