# WCF Endpoint Address using https (WebHttpBinding)

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost, ip-address, endpoint-address

I need to modify a WCF endpoint binding address. Here is some background on the issue:

I have an NT class service (if it matters, not a webservice).  It creates a `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` with an Endpoint whose endpoint address is created this way:

```
var epa = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("https://localhost:{0}/ServiceAPI/", 8181));
```

The binding used for the `ServiceEndpoint` is a `WebHttpBinding` with `Mode=WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport` (i.e. https).

When the ServiceHost is opened, I can go to a command prompt, and do "Netstat -a" and see the address bound to the Listen as 0.0.0.0:8181.

So far, no problem. However, a large customer has raised a "security issue" with the fact that because the WCF "listen" is on address 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, that a potential attacker can connect to that address from an external machine. The test that they have constructed is to use telnet  8181 from an external machine, and if the connect occurs, then the test fails.   The change request is to modify the service to "listen" on 127.0.0.1:8181 so that the only possibility of connecting to that port is from the local machine.

I have done a fair amount of modifications in an attempt to get WCF to "listen" on "127.0.0.1" instead of "0.0.0.0". In all of my attempts the only way to do this is to set `HostNameComparisonMode` to "Exact" and create the endpoint address in this way:

```
var epa = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("https://127.0.0.1:{0}/ServiceAPI/", 8181));
```

(Actually, as an aside, if I use a different binding such as `NetTcpBinding`, the above `EndPointAddress` construction *will* bind to address "127.0.0.1:8181" without altering HostNameComparisonMode. It only switches internally to "0.0.0.0:8181" when I use WebHttpBinding, and fail to set HostNameComparisonMode=Exact.)

However, this (setting HostNameComparisonMode=Exact) causes a breaking complication due to the fact that existing 3rd party code has already been developed that attempts to (onboard the server) connect to "https://localhost:8181/ServiceAPI", and when HostNameComparisonMode is set to "Exact", WCF only ever returns http error 506 to any request due to the difference between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".

What I am currently looking for is either a means of setting up WCF to bind to "127.0.0.1:8181" (as determined by netstat -a) with the HostNameComparisonMode still set to the default "StrongWildcard" setting. Or barring any possibility of there being a way to do that, another creative suggestion to cause connects coming from external machines to be unable to connect to that port.   (The test would be to use "telnet servername 8181" from a different machine, and it fail to connect.)

Any ideas?   Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use https when the requirement then is to only connect from the same box?

Comment: This is a related Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428610/wcf-service-endpoint-localhost-confusion

Comment: hi nvoigt, the same issue arises with http (i.e. WebHttpBinding with Transport.None) It only does not arise with NetTcpBinding.  If one asks why not use, optionally, NetTcpBinding, then, well, --- The application, in general, requires connection from other boxes, and secured using https:.    However, one specific customer wants the application to be configurable so that it is not reachable from outside the box.

Comment: The https scheme on client/server was chosen for customers in general, together with that set of security concerns.   What one customer is seeking is a means of simply, and optionally closing that port.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want to connect from remote machine to this address, so can you try **BasicHttpBinding**? Also you can try to host it at: "https://localhost:{0}/ServiceAPI/", 8181" Correct pls if i understand you wrong.

Comment: I will investigate the use of BasicHttpBinding, and return with a comment on what I find out.

Comment: BasicHttpBinding also internally switches the binding address from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0" just as WebHttpBinding does.

Comment: ok, try pls next: run application, enter in local machine browser "https://localhost:8181/ServiceAPI" - normally you should see wcf server functions. Then try to open in remote machine browser next line: "https://IP of host machine:8181/ServiceAPI" - have you got the same result?

Comment: If I set HostNameComparisonMode to Exact, then the solution fails, because surfing to localhost:8181/ServiceAPI only ever returns http error 506, "Server Not Available", even though it is true that I can no longer get to that port from outside the box.   This would be a solution, except for the fact that it no longer works locally because HostNameComparisonMode.Exact means (here is a reference link: https://kennyw.com/?p=109)

Comment: ....so understandably there is no match between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".    In order for the service to work locally, HostNameComparisonMode _must_ be set to StrongWildCard to overcome the textual comparison difference between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".    However, once I set HostNameComparisonMode=StrongWildCard, suddenly, WCF changes the address binding back to 0.0.0.0, and now I can get to it from outside the box.

Comment: What I need is somehow to leave HostNameComparisonMode=StrongWildCard, and force WCF to bind to the address I told it to, and not switch it internally to "0.0.0.0"

Comment: hm..ok, what if set it to "StrongWildCard", but block this port for remote connections via firewall? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770685(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: That is one of two solutions we are considering as a fallback position.   The customer is resistant to turning on Windows firewall, because as is the case in many large companies that do Qualys analysis, enabling Windows firewall would give the end user the ability to block the Qualys testing (or so I am told).    The other fallback solution is:...

Comment: That we require all 3rd party developed application to use 127.0.0.1 explicitly, and set HostNameComparisonMode=Exact.

Comment: 3rd party app has hardcoded uri, right? i mean no any config)

Comment: Difficult to determine.   It is probably configurable.   There are many 3rd party developers for this application and no way to know for sure.   Most of our direct customers have internal development.    This is definitely a consideration, but the ideal solution would be for there to be some means of configuring WCF to bind to the address that we specified (i.e. 127.0.0.1) and not second-guess us.